# How to make balloon textbook talking style using css

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to call it exactly, these are the example i am working on.
Is is possible to make all of this using html and css on the sqaure and triangle part
or it is better just to use images

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could ue some CSS3 to make the triangle but obviuously it won't work totally cross browser (mainly IE). Safest method is to use an image for the triangle part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Yes it possible to make it using pure css but
```

it shows different result for different browser. i Better suggest you to take help of css and image.

```
<div class="firstDiv">
    <div class="secondDiv"></div>
    <div class="arrowDiv"></div>
</div>

apply following css

.firstDiv { float:left; height:25px; width:200px;}
.secondDiv{ float:left; height:25px; width:170px; background:#666; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:25px; color:#FFF;}
.arrowDiv { float:left; height:25px; width:25px; background:url(images/arrow.png) left no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the code it really appreciate me to work more